# Unable to integrate unisharp\File manager with multi guard login system

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10, unisharp-file-manager

I am developing a multi vendor ecommerce website in laravel-10, to upload images in different interface i hav use Unisharp\File Manager, to handle different users like admin and seller i have created different middlewares like admin for admin users and seller for seller users. i have done the following code and still filemanger bring me to the login page.

**in web.php**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'filemanager', 'middleware' => ['web','auth:admin']], function () {
    \UniSharp\LaravelFilemanager\Lfm::routes();
});
```

**in ConfigHandler**

```
public function userField()
    {
        // return auth()->id();

        if(auth('admin')->check()){
            return auth()->user()->id;
        }else{
            return 'admin';
        }
    }
```

**in web.php**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'filemanager', 'middleware' => ['web','auth:admin']], function () {
    \UniSharp\LaravelFilemanager\Lfm::routes();
});
```

**in ConfigHandler**

```
public function userField()
    {
        // return auth()->id();

        if(auth('admin')->check()){
            return auth()->user()->id;
        }else{
            return 'admin';
        }
    }
```